# Can I transfer every thing in the string to int and keep commas

Tags: python

Example:

```
key = int(input("Enter key:\n"))
encoded = input("Encoded text (with commas) :\n")
decode = encoded
for int in decode:
 int = int - key
 print(chr(int), end = "")
```

so basically what I am trying to do is make the user put the code in and the program should recognize it, substract the key (to make it work with chr() ) and then print the decoded text

Comment: You really shouldn't use `int` for the name of your variable. Especially since you're using the `int` function in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep commas"? An `int` is a number, commas are text.

Comment: @kaya3
```key = int(input("Enter key:\n"))
encoded = input("Encoded text (with commas) :\n")
decode = [117, 102, 116, 117]
for int in decode:
 int = int - key
 print(chr(int), end = "")
```
here the code will work so i want something like that but with user input